# Featuring content with "Existing Node" Panopoly

Tags: nodes, distributions

I am running Drupal 7 with Kalatheme and Panopoly and am looking to feature specific nodes in specific panes on the site. Currently, I am using the the "Existing Node" feature to pull the teaser of a specific node.

The problem is that I am not able to edit or change the node in that pane once it is placed. The content managers will not be able to add a pane each time they want to change the feature, because they will not know the classes and settings of each pane.

Is there a better way to go about featuring specific nodes that will allow our content managers to just change the node featured in that pane, without loosing any settings, or is there a quick fix that will allow us to edit the node as we are currently doing it?